# retrieving STL map keys

Tags: c++, stl

Is there a way (besides storing the key as part of the value and iterating through the map) of retrieving the keys from an STL map, multimap (hash_map) a la Perl keys(%hash)?

Comment: Are you trying to get all the keys, or the key(s) associated with a single value?

Answer (score 14):

```
for (std::map<key, value>::iterator iter = m.begin(); iter != m.end(); ++iter)
    iter->first; // this is the key
```

Comment: +1 Come up with fancy wrappers if you want, but this is what it boils down to.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop.

```
for (const auto & keyVal : myMap)
    keyVal.first;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you often need to get those keys (like in a big loop) then you might be interested in using [boost::bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html). Otherwise you can use Nikola's solution that is correct.

Sometimes I put keys copies in another container when adding elements to a map. It require to be sure to synchronize the two containers but if it's isolated enough (in a class) then it's easy to setup.

Comment: I think `boost::bimap` is an overkill here. There is no bi-directional relation here.

Comment: Yes, as I said it's depends on why it's needed to retrieve the keys.